Using Linq to select multiple values with reflection VB.NET
I'm experimenting with some LINQ in which I'd like my filters to be dynamically loaded at run time and for the result set to be returned as a 2d list of:



Type
Link




Google
steve.jobs@google.com


Google
steve.jobs2@google.com


iCloud
s.jobs@icloud.com


iCloud
s.jobs@me.com



At the moment, I can return the Link value but cannot match this up with the type.
My JSON looks like this
{
    "Name": "Steve Jobs",
    "Email": [
        {
            "Type": "Google",
            "Link": "steve.jobs@google.com",
            "altLink": "secret.address@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Type": "Google",
            "Link": "steve.jobs2@google.com",
            "altLink": "secret.address2@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Type": "iCloud",
            "Link": "s.jobs@icloud.com"
        },
        {
            "Type": "iCloud",
            "Link": "s.jobs@me.com"
        },
        {
            "Type": "AO",
            "Link": "s.jobs@me.com"
        }
    ]
}

and this is translated into a VB.Net class structure of the same.
The LINQ I have so far that just returns the Link value is:
Dim addressType As List(Of String) = Nothing
addressType.Add("Google")
addressType.Add("iCloud")

dim columnName as string = "Link"
        
Dim ResultDataSet = Person.Email _
    .Where(Function(emailType) addressType.Contains(emailType.Type)) _
    .Select(Function(LinkData) LinkData.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(LinkData)) _
    .ToList()

The code above looks quite poor, but functions and data being passed through happens on the program and I've just written everything with variables to make it look easier

I’m voting to close this question because requests for reviews of existing, working code belong on Code Review.

@GertArnold - this code doesn't work

@GertArnold It looks to me like the issue is that the current code is only returning the "Link" whereas it's supposed to return the pair "Type" & "Link".

The code as written is only trying to get the "Link".  What else have you tried to also get "Type"?  It seems like it should be a straightforward modification of your Select.

Both the Where and the Select are passed predicates with the same signature, so using emailType and LinkData is confusing - the arguments are of the same type.

@Craig - I can't seem to get the select to return both? This is the part I'm struggling on.

If you want to return it as a concatenated string, you have LinkData as the argument to the lambda in the Select, so just tack on LinkData.Type.  You can use ToString on the return from the property call, it's always defined on Object and should be an identity function when the type is String.

Or just return them both in a Tuple

You can retrieve both the Type and Link using a Tuple:
Dim ResultDataSet = Person.Email.
    Where(Function(e) addressType.Contains(e.Type)).
    Select(Function(e) (e.Type, e.Link)).
    ToList()

For Each result In ResultDataSet
    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {result.Type}, Link: {result.Link}")
Next

Alternatively, you can serialize your json to .NET classes:
Imports System.Text.Json ' (NuGet Package)

' model
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Email() As Email
End Class

Public Class Email
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Link As String
    Public Property altLink As String
End Class

Using s As New FileStream("filename.json", FileMode.Open)
    Dim person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(s)
    Dim addressTypes As New List(Of String) From {"Google", "iCloud"}
    Dim results = person.Email.Where(Function(e) addressTypes.Contains(e.Type)).ToList()
    For Each result In results
        Debug.WriteLine($"Type: {result.Type}, Link: {result.Link}")
    Next
End Using

Either way, the output is the same:

Type: Google, Link: steve.jobs@google.com
Type: Google, Link: steve.jobs2@google.com
Type: iCloud, Link: s.jobs@icloud.com
Type: iCloud, Link: s.jobs@me.com

By the way, this code won't work since you're trying to add to a List which is null. Construct the list...
Dim addressType As List(Of String) = Nothing
addressType.Add("Google")
addressType.Add("iCloud")

